# Custom Normalization for NDEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I am trying to solve the Laplace equation in polar coordinates
$$-\left(\frac{\partial^2\psi_n(r,\theta)}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\psi_n(r,\theta)}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2\psi_n(r,\theta)}{\partial\theta^2}\right)=E_n\psi_n(r,\theta)$$

numerically using the NDEigensystem package. Here is my code

```
{vals, funs} = 
NDEigensystem[{-(D[D[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]], r], r] + (1/r)*
   D[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]], r] + (1/r^2)*
   D[D[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]], \[Theta]])}, 
u, {r, 0, 25}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, 5]
```

The problem is the functions should satisfy a very specific normalization condition, that is
$$\int_{0}^{10}dr\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\ r\psi^*(r,\theta)\psi(r,\theta)=1$$
How can I implement this normalization condtition to the code I have provided?

Note: I know Laplace equation can be solved exactly, but I am providing this simple case because I want to use the normalization condition for a much harder problem with the same normalization condition.

I looked at a similar question and modified the code in the following way

```
{vals, funs} = 
NDEigensystem[{-(D[D[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]], r], r] + (1/r)*
    D[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]], r] + (1/r^2)*
    D[D[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]], \[Theta]]), 
DirichletCondition[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]] == 0, True]}, \[Psi][
r, \[Theta]], {r, 0, 25}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, 50, 
Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
   "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}, 
 "VectorNormalization" -> 
  Function[{values, vectors, stiffness, damping}, s = stiffness; 
   d = damping;
   norm = 
    vectors/(Diagonal[
         vectors . damping . ConjugateTranspose[vectors]]^(1/2)*
       NIntegrate[r, {r, 0, 25}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}])]}];
```

But when I test it

```
NIntegrate[
r*Conjugate[funs[[1]]]*funs[[1]], {r, 0, 25}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}]
(*3.15701*10^-6*)
```

I get an unpleasant result

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you look into NIntegrate to just evaluate the necessary consant and divide your `funs` variable with it?

Comment: I am not sure whether dividing each eigenfunction with its norm would be a good solution. Imposing the proper normalization condition can fix lot of the convergence issues in the future.

Comment: @JulienKluge I added an example.

Comment: Your boundary conditions are (I think) not going to to yield what you want.  Mathematica doesn't know that `th` is an angular coordinate *a priori* and applies the Dirichlet boundary conditions to the "boundaries" $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2\pi$ as well.  I think you want periodic boundary conditions for $\theta$ instead;  the first example in the "Applications" section of the `NDEigensystem` documentation shows how to implement the correct boundary conditions for a disk.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That is no help for me. I am not using cartesian coordinates. Most importantly I can not use cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I need dirichlet conditions for $r=25$ and a periodic boundary condition for $\theta$. How can I implement both of them?

Comment: @gsuer: My mistake, I meant the first example in the "Applications" section of `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`.

Comment: Also, why can't you use Cartesian coordinates and solve over the domain `{x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 25]`?  The coordinate singularity at $r = 0$ is going to be a nuisance if you're forced to use polar coordinates.  By contrast, if you use Cartesian coordinates, the eigenfunctions will be normalized by default, since your normalization is equivalent to $\int \psi^*(x,y) \psi(x,y) \, dx\, dy = 1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128973/discussion-between-michael-seifert-and-gsuer).

Answer (score 3):

You can always tell Mathematica not to normalize the eigenvectors and then normalize them yourself:

```
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{-(D[D[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]], r], r] + (1/r)*
                 D[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]], r] + (1/r^2)*
                 D[D[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]], \[Theta]]), 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]] == 0, r == 25 && 0 < \[Theta] <= 2 \[Pi]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[\[Psi][r, \[Theta]], \[Theta] == 0, TranslationTransform[{0, 2 \[Pi]}]]}, 
   \[Psi][r, \[Theta]], {r, 0, 25}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, 5,
   Method -> {"VectorNormalization" -> None}];

norms = Table[
          NIntegrate[r*Conjugate[funs[[i]]]*funs[[i]], {r, 0, 25}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}],
         {i, 1, 5}]

(* {0.784731, 1.30076, 1.39706, 1.70865, 0.623398} *)
```

You can then divide by the appropriate factor to create normalized eigenfunctions:

```
normalizedfuns = funs/Sqrt[norms];
Table[NIntegrate[r*Conjugate[normalizedfuns[[i]]]*normalizedfuns[[i]], {r, 0, 25}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}],
     {i, 1, 5}]

(* {1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)
```

Mathematica throws a warning about slow convergence when integrating these functions;  I'm not sure why.